# How often can I apply bokashi juice?

Tags: fertilizer

I have successfully setup a bokashi fermentation bucket. I'm currently harvesting bokashi juice and have applied it to some plants.

I'm harvesting bokashi juice daily now. How often can or should I apply this juice to plants? Once a week? Once a month? Once a quarter?

Answer (score 1):

Bokashi juice straight from the bokashi bucket can be too acidic and harsh for many plants.  It is usually recommended to dilute it with water to about 1:100 and then water the soil around the plants directly with it.

[Bokashi Organko recommends](https://bokashiorganko.com/bokashi-library/bokashi-liquid-for-plants#:%7E:text=Furthermore%2C%20while%20there,should%20normally%20suffice.) only doing this to each plant once per 14 days, or to dilute it further if you will apply it more often.  Then only increase the use if the plants appear to need the nutrients.  I think this is a cautious approach but not a bad one.